# Combining list with same element with addition of integers

Tags: python

I have a nested list how can I make the same elements removed with addition of its numbers.

What my list contains:

```
lis = [['apple', 32], ['Blue shirt', 323], ['Blue shirt', 320]]
```

I want this `'Blue Shirt'` to merge, to make this:

```
lis = [['apple', 32], ['Blue shirt', 643]]
```

what i've tried so far

```
lis = [['apple',32],['Blue shirt',323],['Blue shirt',320]]
l = -1
new = 0
n = []
for i in lis:
    l+=1
    if lis[l][0] in i:
        count = lis[l].count('Blue shirt')
        if count > 1:
            new += lis[l][1]
            n.append(new)
            name = lis[l][0]
            n.append(name)
            lis.pop(l)

print(n)
```

My approch was to count the occurrence of name if its more than 2 then make a new list with that name and updated price and put it in the place of the previous list but it was not simple enough.

I am trying the count function but its seems to not work efficiently on a nested list. Would love to have to most simplest option to solve this without using some external functions (imports).

Comment: Why is the new list nested further? Wouldn't `[['apple', 32], ['Blue shirt', 643]]` do?

Comment: And how did you use the count function? Have you considered using `collections.Counter()`?

Comment: i haven't used the counter yet but i am using the count function inside a for loop

Comment: Can you share your code that isn't working?

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.count('Blue shirt')` counts how many times the string `'Blue shirt'` is present in a list. That's exactly once, and not a useful number for your needs.

You want to put your strings into a dictionary, so you can track the numbers without having to do a full scan:

```
counts = {}
for name, count in lis:
    counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + count
```

Now you have a mapping with the sums of all your numbers; turn that back into a list of lists:

```
lis = [[name, count] for name, count in counts.items()]
```

This doesn't necessarily keep the same order as the elements in the input list. If that's needed, you'd have to loop over the original list and see if the name string is still there, and if so, add the name and count from the mapping to a new list and remove the name from the mapping:

```
ordered_lis = []
for name, __ in lis:
    if name in counts:
        ordered_lis.append([name, counts.pop(name)])
```

However, in Python 3.6 and newer, dictionaries will remember the insertion order of keys, meaning that the loop over `counts.items()` gives you your strings in the original first-seen order again.

Demo, using Python 3.6:

```
>>> lis = [['apple', 32], ['Blue shirt', 323], ['Blue shirt', 320]]
>>> counts = {}
>>> for name, count in lis:
...     counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + count
...
>>> [[name, count] for name, count in counts.items()]
[['apple', 32], ['Blue shirt', 643]]
```

If you can use the standard library, then you could also use a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object to avoid having to use `counts.get(name, 0)` (you'd use `counts = defaultdict(int)` outside the loop, and `counts[name] += 1` in the loop instead), or [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for the dictionary to remember insertion order on Python versions before Python 3.6.

Comment: I will upvote yours for the detailed clarification of your solution, and I loved the Python 3.6 explanation.

Comment: hi thanks for the solution. But i wonder if i have 2 values for example ['Blue shirt', 643 , 2] how can i make it inside the list

Comment: @NoobSaibot: that's not enough information for me to help. Do those numbers have different meaning? Are they counts to be added up? Can you give a good input example and the expected output?

Comment: hi , thanks for replying .. Imagine i have the same list
[['apple', 32 , 2], ['Blue shirt', 323 , 3], ['Blue shirt', 320 , 1]]

these 3rd numbers are actually quanitity that needed to be added as well just like the same way price  were summing up.. I need these qty to sum up to other qty as well

Comment: the output would be  [['apple', 32 , 2], ['Blue shirt', 643 , 4]]

Comment: @NoobSaibot: then use *two* dictionaries. One to track quantity, the other to track prices. Then when looping to build the output, loop over one of the dictionaries, and use the same key on the other. `for name, cost, count in lis:` and `costs[name] = costs.get(name, 0)` and `counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + count`, and in the output `[[name, cost, counts[name]] for name, cost in costs.items()]`.

Answer (score 3):

Using only base Python:

```
grouped = dict.fromkeys((x[0] for x in lis), 0) # count dict with unique lis names

for el in lis:
    grouped[el[0]] += el[1] # sum values per name

[[k,v] for k, v in grouped.items()] # convert back to list
#[['apple', 32], ['Blue shirt', 643]]
```

Not sure if "external functions" means no additional imports - but if you can use Pandas, use `groupby` and `sum`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(lis).groupby(0, as_index=False).sum().values

array([['Blue shirt', 643],
       ['apple', 32]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Updated with base Python solution.

Comment: You can drop the `[` and `]` brackets from the `set()` call and just pass in a generator expression. That avoids creating a new list object just to be discarded again once `set()` is done. And then you should replace the `set()` with a `{...}` set comprehension, while you are at it: `names = {x[0] for x in lis}`. However, you then never use the `names` other than to produce a dictionary, so you could just use `grouped = dict.fromkeys((x[0] for x in lis), 0)`.

Comment: Wow, great.  Thanks for the instruction @Martijn Pieters.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not able to use neither an external library nor `collections.Counter()` The following solution might help you:

```
lis = [['apple', 32], ['Blue shirt', 323], ['Blue shirt', 320]]
d = {}

for (name, count) in lis:
    d[name] = d.get('name', 0) + count

lis = [[name, count] for name, count in d.items()]
```

The problem using `list.count()` is that it just applies to a single list, but you are having a list of lists. Basically, my solution uses a dictionary that has as keys the items you need to count and as values the count. Then I use a list comprehension to produce your desire output.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to use without any libraries (like `collections.Counter`):

```
lis = [['apple',32],['Blue shirt',323],['Blue shirt',320]]

d = {}

for name, item in lis:
    try:
        d[name] += item
    except KeyError:
        d[name] = item

lis = [[k ,v] for k, v in d.items()]
print(lis)
```

Output:

```
[['apple', 32], ['Blue shirt', 643]]
```